# How to assign a code to xlabels in bar plot

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, matplotlib, visualization

I am working on global terrorism database and trying to plot a bar plot of various target types of terrorists.
I want to assign a code to every xlabel and print a legend on the graph showing corresponding codes with the target types

Till now I have not found any solution to this problem.
[Link](https://www.kaggle.com/START-UMD/gtd) to the dataset in consideration.

```py
df['targtype1_txt'].value_counts().plot(kind = 'bar')
plt.title("Favoirite Target types of Terrorist")
plt.xlabel("Target Type")
plt.ylabel("Value_Counts")
```

[Link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0WgqT.png) to output of the above code.
I would like to map the values of xlabel to some numerical code and put it as list on the side of the plot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```
c = df.targtype1_txt.astype('category')
d = dict(enumerate(c.cat.categories))
df['targtype1_txt_code'] = c.cat.codes
df['targtype1_txt_code'].value_counts().plot(kind = 'bar')
plt.title("Favorite Target types of Terrorist")
plt.xlabel("Target Type")
plt.xticks(rotation=0)
plt.ylabel("Value_Counts")
s ='\n'.join(['%s: %s' % (key, value) for (key, value) in d.items()])
plt.text(2.6, 1, s, fontsize=14)
```

Create a new column with a code for each value and plot that column. Then add a text box on the side using the dictionary that has been used to code the values.

Output (with few values):
[image]

Comment: Thanks, since the dataset already contains a column for codes I will only make a dictionary and plot it using the above outlined method